# Rails: Pass ID of nested resource from button_to to controller / to toggle boolean in admin view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, nested, boolean, button-to

I am sitting here since the Dawn of Times trying to toggle a boolean in Rails for an admin to validate submissions.

I have a standard "Article" model, which has_many "Prosols" (which in turn belongs_to "Article").
A Prosol has a boolean "profeat1".
I am trying to toggle it thanks to a set of button_to (as follows).
I am looping through the articles prosols, showing them in a bootstrap template, and showing for each a button to validate or not. 
The issue is that all buttons point to the first prosol. It seems that the prosol ID is not accurately passed to the controller.

```
No route matches {:action=>"unpro1", :article_id=>5, :controller=>"prosols", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

Here is the code.

article#show.html.erb - Adding lines from original Code

```
<% if admin_signed_in? %>

<% @article.prosols.in_groups_of(2) do |group| %>
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <% group.compact.each do |prosol| %>

  <div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="box3">
  <h4><%= prosol.title %></h4> <br>
  <%= prosol.body %> <br>

  <% if prosol.profeat1 == false %>
    <%= button_to "Do it", pro1_article_prosol_path(:article_id => @article.id, :id => @prosol.id), :class => 'btn btn-info'%>

  <% else %>
    <%= button_to "Undo it", unpro1_article_prosol_path(:article_id => @article.id, :id => @prosol.id), :class => 'btn btn-info'%>

  <% end %>
</div>
</div>
<% end %>
</div>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

prosols_controller.rb

```
def pro1
  @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
  @prosol = @article.prosols.find(params[:id])
  @prosol.update(profeat1: true)
  redirect_to article_path(@article)
end

def unpro1
  @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
  @prosol = @article.prosols.find(params[:id])    
  @prosol.update(profeat1: false)
  redirect_to article_path(@article)
end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :articles do
  resources :prosols do
    post 'pro1', on: :member
    post 'unpro1', on: :member
  end
end
```

Right now I think the issue is with passing the nested resource (prosol) ID to controller.
If you see a better/different way of achieving the end result, I will warmly welcome your advice.
Again, my goal is to display all prosols for an article, with an admin button to validate or not.
I have thoroughly tried everything else on StackO so far but to no avail.

Awaiting the Savior... Thanks in advance.

EDIT : THIS IS THE SOLUTION - article#show.html.erb

```
<% if prosol.profeat1 == false %>
  <%= button_to "Do it", pro1_article_prosol_path(:article_id => @article.id, :id => prosol.id), :class => 'btn btn-info'%>

<% else %>
  <%= button_to "Undo it", unpro1_article_prosol_path(:article_id => @article.id, :id => prosol.id), :class => 'btn btn-info'%>

<% end %>
```

My initial error had 2 sources:
- pointing to the nested prosol with an @ instead of no pointer, as it was already pointed to in the loop
- and bad leftovers in the Articles controller, as follows:

```
def show
 @article = Article.find(params[:id])
 @prosols = @article.prosols.all    <--- wrong
 @prosol = @article.prosols.build   <--- wrong
end
```

Great. Now it's beer o'clock.

Comment: Where are you setting @prosol for the link itself?

Comment: Good point. The code in the "show" view above is embedded into a loop:  <% @article.prosols.in_groups_of(2) do |group| %>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <% group.compact.each do |prosol| %>

Comment: can you update your question with the View code and the Action from the controller that sets those params?

Comment: `<% if prosol.profeat1 == false %>` shouldnt there be an @?

Comment: @DevDude thanks for your feedback. I updated the code. But which controller Action do you mean for setting the params ? :id should be set at creation, and the methods pro1 and unpro1 are supposed to find the ids ?

Comment: @forthowin thanks for your feedback but that did not change. I am often confused about when to use/not use an @ but this time it is fine.

Comment: add a `binding.pry` before `<% if prosol.profeat1 == false %>`, what do you see?

Comment: I never heard about Pry before, will definitely give it a pry, thanks for the tip. My error stemmed from a leftover in the Articles controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be that you are using @prosol in your button, which has not been assigned and is therefore returning nil.

Your loop defined in your comment, sets prosol, which is not @prosol. Drop the '@' symbol and you should be fine.

-- edit--

As in `id => prosol.id` ...

```
  <% if prosol.profeat1 == false %>
    <%= button_to "Do it", ..., :id => prosol.id), :class => 'btn btn-info'%>

  <% else %>
    <%= button_to "Undo it", ..., :id => prosol.id), :class => 'btn btn-info'%>

  <% end %>
```

Your error is showing `id => nil` because @prosil is a nil object.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried some relevant changes as in the edit above. :id in itself is not recognized, but prosol.id is. Now the issue is that all buttons toggle the first one, which mean they only point to the first prosol.id they find, I believe... I am not sure how to get out of this.

Comment: Just made my answer more explicit,

Comment: I follow your logic and theoretically concur with it; but when trying this exact bit of code, I still get: No route matches {:action=>"pro1", :article_id=>5, :class=>"btn btn-info", :controller=>"prosols", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

Comment: Well I just found the issue. It was some leftovers in the Articles controller. I'll edit my initial question. Your code works. Awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't this:

```
<% if prosol.profeat1 == false %>
  <%= button_to "Do it", pro1_article_prosol_path(:article_id => @article.id, prosol.id => prosol.id), :class => 'btn btn-info'%>

<% else %>
  <%= button_to "Undo it", unpro1_article_prosol_path(:article_id => @article.id, prosol.id => prosol.id), :class => 'btn btn-info'%>

<% end %>
```

look like this?

```
<% if prosol.profeat1 == false %>
  <%= button_to "Do it", pro1_article_prosol_path(:article_id => @article.id, :id => prosol.id), :class => 'btn btn-info'%>

<% else %>
  <%= button_to "Undo it", unpro1_article_prosol_path(:article_id => @article.id, :id => prosol.id), :class => 'btn btn-info'%>

<% end %>
```

Or even better:

```
<% if prosol.profeat1 == false %>
  <%= button_to "Do it", pro1_article_prosol_path(@article, prosol), :class => 'btn btn-info'%>

<% else %>
  <%= button_to "Undo it", unpro1_article_prosol_path(@article, prosol), :class => 'btn btn-info'%>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Oh yes it should. But when trying this, Rails is not in the mood and is telling me that "No route matches {:action=>"pro1", :article_id=>"5", :controller=>"prosols", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]       but thanks anyway

Comment: Ok this code totally works. Awesome. My error stemmed from leftovers in the Article controller. I'll edit the question.